Is every set an open set?
I'm reading Rudin's "Principles of mathematical analysis", definition 2.18 stated that:
"A neighborhood of $p$ is a set $N_{r}(p)$ consisting of all $q$ such that
$d(p,q)<r$, for some $r>0$."
This does not require that $q$ is a different point from $p$.
"A point $p$ is an interior point of $E$ if there is a neighborhood $N$ of $p$ such that $N\subset E$."
Then every point $p \in E$ is an interior point because we can always have a neighborhood containing only $p$. Thus every set will be open since every point can be an interior point.
However, he later stated that "A nonempty finite set is not open" in an example right below. Is he just forgot to add the constraint that a neighborhood can not contain only one point or I'm missing something here ?

The definition of neighborhood says $N_r(p)$ consists of all $q$ such that $d(p,q) < r$. Why do you believe this means the singleton ${p}$ is a neighborhood of $p$?

unless $p$ is "isolated" (e.g. $0$ in ${0} \cup [1, 2]$), $N_r(p)$ will have more points than just $p$ for each $r > 0$. This means that $N_r(p)$ may "poke out" of $E$, which is the problem

You have not understood the "for every" in the definition of neighborhood. There is no neighborhood that contains a single point since $r> 0$ in the definition, (Points are open sets in the discrete topology but that's not what you are asking about.)

"Then every point $p \in E$ is an interior point because we can always have a neighborhood containing only $p$." This is not true. Take $E = {3}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.  The neighborhoods of $3$ are of the form $(3-r, 3+r)$ for $r > 0$ and no such neighborhood is a subset of $E$.

Actually, this does not even look like the usual definition of neighbourhood in a metric space.

If $E=[0,1],$ then $0$ is not an interior point because the ball of radius $r>0$ centered at $0$ is $N_r=(-r,r),$ which contains points which are not in $E,$ for example $-r/2.$
